# Extract subtitles from mp4 without time marks or position locators

Tags: mp4, video-subtitles

I have an mp4 from a university lecture that has embedded subtitles. I am aware there are tools to extract the captions.

The lecturer is reading from a script which we don't have access to. I just want to extract all the text of the subtitles without the time stamps so I have the text in a word document to study.

Is this possible? If not, is there any tool or script that could help me eliminate the post-extraction time stamps?

Comment: Try looking at this question: [How to extract subtitle from video using ffmpeg?](https://superuser.com/q/583393/968848)